# Vue 3. Video.js. Selecting audio tracks for the video

Tags: vue.js, html5-video, video.js

Is it possible to get all or switch between audio tracks in MKV video with video.js?
Video has several track how can I switch between them?

videojs.audioTracks returns empty.

Comment: If it's important, then you'll have to learn about media Source Extensions. Youll have to also know both MKV and MP4 layouts in order to extract audio frame(s) from MKV and package with one picture frame inside (fragmented) MP4 to play in MSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Videojs notes in their documentation that they do not support switching audio tracks:

> Video.js only stores track representations. Switching audio tracks for playback is not handled by Video.js and must be handled elsewhere - for example, videojs-contrib-hls handles switching audio tracks to support track selection through the UI.

One other note, given you are using MKV video container which is not supported on some browsers and which videojs may not fully support also, you may run into additional problems. If you have the option of using a more widely supported container it might help.